# Mixing ASP.Net MVC custom routing and partial views in a ASP.Net web forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, web-parts, httpcontext

I’m trying to migrate slowly from a CMS written in ASP.Net web forms to ASP.Net MVC. In order to do that I need to replace the functionality from web parts (custom controls) to the functionality from partial views. A CMS page contains many web parts and each one should render eventually some html from the MVC partial view. Also I need a way to pass the parameters set in each web part, and based on these to construct the partial view.  The whole purpose is to decouple business logic from presentation, to remove the dependency to the CMS itself. During the process all web parts should still work. 
Do you have any idea or suggestions about an efficient way to achieve that?

This is my starting point. I'm trying to retrieve an MVC partial view as a string outside of the ASP.Net pipeline. In order to do that I need to use HttpContext. Since I don't have this context (I want to use only the bare minimum of properties passed through some interfaces) I tried to create a fake one.

```
public class TestController : Controller, ICmsTranslator
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string RenderAsString(IHttpRequest request, IContext context)
    {
        return RenderRazorViewToString("~/Views/Shared/_TestPartialView.cshtml", new TestModels(), request, context);
    }

    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model, IHttpRequest request, IContext context)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            // create a fake HttpContext
            var fakeRouteData = new RouteData();
            if (!fakeRouteData.Values.ContainsKey("controller") && !fakeRouteData.Values.ContainsKey("Controller"))
            {
                fakeRouteData.Values.Add("controller", GetType().Name
                                                             .ToLower()
                                                             .Replace("controller", ""));
            }
            HttpContextBase offlineContextBase = new OfflineHttpContext(viewName, request, context);
            var offlineControllerContext = new ControllerContext(offlineContextBase, fakeRouteData, this);

            // try to use the fake context to get the partial view
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(offlineControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(offlineControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(offlineControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}




public class OfflineHttpContext : HttpContextBase
{   
    private readonly Hashtable _items = new Hashtable();
    private IPrincipal _user;
    private readonly IHttpRequest _request;
    private readonly IContext _context;
    private readonly string _relativeUrl;

    public OfflineHttpContext(string relativeUrl, IHttpRequest request, IContext context)
    {
        _relativeUrl = relativeUrl;
        _request = request;
        _context = context;
    }

    public override Exception[] AllErrors
    {
        get { return new Exception[0]; }
    }

    public override Cache Cache
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override HttpRequestBase Request
    {
        get
        {
            var serverVariables = new NameValueCollection
                                      {
                                          {"HTTP_HOST", "www.example.com"},
                                          {"APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH", _context.PhysicalPath}
                                      };

            var headers = new NameValueCollection();
            foreach (var header in _request.Headers)
            {
                headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
            var formParams = new NameValueCollection();
            var queryStringParams = new NameValueCollection();
            var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();

            HttpRequestBase httpContext = new OfflineHttpRequest(_relativeUrl, _request.Method, formParams, queryStringParams, cookies, serverVariables, headers);
            return httpContext;
        }
    }

    public override HttpResponseBase Response
    {
        get
        { 
            var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
            return new HttpResponseWrapper(httpResponse);
        }
    }

    public override IDictionary Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public override IPrincipal User
    {
        get
        {
            if (_user == null)
            {
                // User is logged in
                return new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("public"), new string[0]);
                // User is logged out
                // return new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(""), new string[0]);
            }
            return _user;
        }
        set { _user = value; }
    }
}


public class OfflineHttpRequest : HttpRequestBase
{
    private readonly HttpCookieCollection _cookies;
    private readonly NameValueCollection _formParams;
    private readonly NameValueCollection _queryStringParams;
    private readonly NameValueCollection _headers;
    private readonly NameValueCollection _serverVariables;
    private readonly string _relativeUrl;
    private readonly Uri _url;
    private readonly Uri _urlReferrer;
    private readonly string _httpMethod;

    public OfflineHttpRequest(
        string relativeUrl, 
        string httpMethod,
        NameValueCollection formParams, 
        NameValueCollection queryStringParams,
        HttpCookieCollection cookies, 
        NameValueCollection serverVariables, 
        NameValueCollection headers)
    {
        _httpMethod = httpMethod;
        _relativeUrl = relativeUrl;
        _formParams = formParams;
        _queryStringParams = queryStringParams;
        _cookies = cookies;
        _serverVariables = serverVariables;
        _headers = headers;

        //ensure collections are not null
        if (_formParams == null)
        {
            _formParams = new NameValueCollection();
        }
        if (_queryStringParams == null)
        {
            _queryStringParams = new NameValueCollection();
        }
        if (_cookies == null)
        {
            _cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
        }
        if (_serverVariables == null)
        {
            _serverVariables = new NameValueCollection();
        }
        if (_headers == null)
        {
            _headers = new NameValueCollection();
        }
    }

    public OfflineHttpRequest(
        string relativeUrl,
        string httpMethod, 
        Uri url, 
        Uri urlReferrer,
        NameValueCollection formParams, 
        NameValueCollection queryStringParams,
        HttpCookieCollection cookies, 
        NameValueCollection serverVariables,
        NameValueCollection headers)
        : this(relativeUrl, httpMethod, formParams, queryStringParams, cookies, serverVariables, headers)
    {
        _url = url;
        _urlReferrer = urlReferrer;
        _headers = headers;
    }

    public OfflineHttpRequest(
        string relativeUrl, 
        Uri url, 
        Uri urlReferrer)
        : this(relativeUrl, HttpVerbs.Get.ToString("g"), url, urlReferrer, null, null, null, null, null)
    {
    }

    public override NameValueCollection ServerVariables
    {
        get
        {
            return _serverVariables;
        }
    }

    public override NameValueCollection Form
    {
        get { return _formParams; }
    }

    public override NameValueCollection QueryString
    {
        get { return _queryStringParams; }
    }

    public override NameValueCollection Headers
    {
        get { return _headers; }
    }

    public override HttpCookieCollection Cookies
    {
        get { return _cookies; }
    }

    public override string AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
    {
        get { return _relativeUrl; }
    }

    public override Uri Url
    {
        get
        {
            return _url;
        }
    }

    public override Uri UrlReferrer
    {
        get
        {
            return _urlReferrer;
        }
    }

    public override string Path
    {
        get
        {
            if (_relativeUrl != null && _relativeUrl.StartsWith("~/"))
            { 
                return _relativeUrl.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override string PathInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public override string PhysicalApplicationPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _serverVariables.Get("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH");
        }
    }

    public override string PhysicalPath
    {
        get
        {
            var file = "";
            if (Path != null && Path.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                file = Path.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            if (PhysicalApplicationPath != null)
            {
                return PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\" + file.Replace('/', '\\');
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override string HttpMethod
    {
        get
        {
            return _httpMethod;
        }
    }

    public override string UserHostAddress
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override string RawUrl
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override bool IsSecureConnection
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override string UserAgent
    {
        get
        {
            var agent = _headers.Get("User-Agent") ??
                           "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html)";
            return agent;
        }
    }

    public override HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase Browser
    {
        get
        {
            var browser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities
            {
                Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, UserAgent } }
            };
            var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
            factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), browser);

            return new HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper(browser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is what I'm trying to use but there's an exception thrown related to the VirtualPath being null. When I use my fake context here: ... 
    ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(offlineControllerContext, viewName); ... under the hood VirtualPathProvider is using the ASP.Net HttpContext, not my fake context.

Answer (score 0):

This is an MvcUtility Class I use when I would like to render PartialViews or ChildActions in a Webforms Page, I don't think I have used it in a UserControl however.

Not sure what MVC version you are using but I know this works with MVC 3 and Razor Views.

```
public static class MvcUtility
{
        public static void RenderPartial(string partialViewName, object model)
        {
            // Get the HttpContext
            HttpContextBase httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            // Build the route data, pointing to the Some controller
            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", typeof(Controller).Name);
            // Create the controller context
            ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContextBase, routeData), new Controller());
            // Find the partial view
            IView view = FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName);
            // create the view context and pass in the model
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, view, new ViewDataDictionary { Model = model }, new TempDataDictionary(), httpContextBase.Response.Output);
            // finally, render the view
            view.Render(viewContext, httpContextBase.Response.Output);
        }

        private static IView FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName)
        {
            // try to find the partial view
            ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName);
            if (result.View != null)
            {
                return result.View;
            }
            // wasn't found - construct error message
            StringBuilder locationsText = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string location in result.SearchedLocations)
            {
                locationsText.AppendLine();
                locationsText.Append(location);
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Partial view {0} not found. Locations Searched: {1}", partialViewName, locationsText));
        }

        public static void RenderAction(string controllerName, string actionName, object routeValues)
        {
            RenderPartial("RenderActionUtil", new RenderActionVM() { ControllerName = controllerName, ActionName = actionName, RouteValues = routeValues });
        }
    }
```

To render a ChildAction you will need a partial view in the Shared MVC Views Folder:

```
@model YourNamespace.RenderActionVM

@{
    Html.RenderAction(Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, Model.RouteValues);
}
```

And the View Model:

```
public class RenderActionVM
{
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public object RouteValues { get; set; }
}
```

And finally in your webforms page call like this:

```
<% MvcUtility.RenderPartial("_SomePartial", null); %> 

<% MvcUtility.RenderAction("SomeController", "SomeAction", new { accountID = Request.QueryString["id"], dateTime = DateTime.Now }); %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my scenario HttpContext.Current will throw an exception since HttpContext is null. That's why I'm trying to fake it.